# CSS: float:left align up

Tags: html, css

I used `float:left` and now my text looks like

```
.   A   .   B   .   C  .
.     a .     b .      . 
.       .     b .   D  .
.       .     b .     d.
.       .       .     d.
.       .       .     d.
.   E   .    F  .      .
.       .     f .      .
```

But I want

```
.   A   .   B   .   C  .
.     a .     b .      . 
.       .     b .   D  .
.   E   .     b .     d.
.   F   .       .     d.
.      f.       .     d.
.      f.       .      .
.      f.       .      .
```

I have tried `"display: inline-block"`
but it looks like

```
.   A   .   B   .   C  .
.     a .     b .      . 
.       .     b .      .
.       .     b .      .
.   E   .   D   .   F  .
.       .     d .     f.
.       .     d .     f.
.       .     d .     f.
.       .       .      .
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: why not post a jsfiddle demo to better illustrate the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what do u mean text ? can u add the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS does not currently allow you to do that, unfortunately. However, there are some JavaScript libraries that can do layouts like this. One popular choice is [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to copy old jsp code to the new jsp code. I missed preview code like class = "xxx masonry". It is working now.